# Nullish coalescing operator only if there's a change in the variable

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do something like this using [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) ?

```
if (content) document.elem.innerHTML = content;
```

This is not what I want :

```
document.elem.innerHTML = content ?? document.elem.innerHTML;
```

I don't want re-assignment of `document.elem.innerHTML` if content is null.

Comment: Why do you need the nullish coalescing operator? You can simply use the and thingamajig like so: `content && document.elem.innerHTML = content;`.

Comment: An `if` statement would be more appropriate. Your current code is fine

Comment: content && (document.elem.innerHTML = content). You'll get SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment if no brackets are used.